# Implementing pagination in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, pagination

I'm trying to implement a pretty basic pagination & filtering support with backbone

so far now, I have something like this on my Collection.url() function:

```
url: function() {
  var url = 'http://localhost:9000/wines';
  var query = '';

  if (this.filter)  query += '&filter=' + this.filter;
  if (this.order)   query += '&order='  + this.order;
  if (this.page)    query += '&page='   + this.page.toString();
  if (this.len)     query += '&len='    + this.len.toString();

  if (query) url += '?' + query.substring(1);

  return url;
},
```

you get the idea

the problem is that when I'm trying to create (POST) or update (PUT) an item, the querystring is also sent to the browser...

is there some way, in the url function, to detect the operation I'm issuing and add the querystring parameters only when fetching (GET) data?

or would you recommend another approach???

Answer (score 0):

I found the following way to do it

I just override the fetch method, like this:

```
initialize: function(options) {

  this._fetch = this.fetch;

  this.fetch = function() {
    options = {};
    options.url = 'http://localhost:9000/wines'

    data = {};
    if (this.filter) data.filter = this.filter;
    if (this.order) data.order = this.order;
    if (this.page) data.page = this.page;
    if (this.len) data.len = this.len;

    options.data = data;

    return this._fetch(options);
  }
},
```

I couln't find a way to avoid saving the _fetch variable, I tried with

return Backbone.Collection.fetch(options);
return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch(options);

return Wines.fetch(options);
return Wines.prototype.fetch(options);

but none of them seems to work...

--
edit

found it on backbone page:

return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);